# Node Red - flows stopped due to missing nodes error on startup

Tags: node-red

My node red flows were working fine but when I restarted them, they started giving me this error. Nothing has changed between the time it worked and now. Any clue what the error could be?

I already checked configuration nodes tab for missing nodes and that was of no help

Comment: Check the node-red log to see what user dir and flows file are being used -- typically, when this happens, it's just because you were not in the `~/.node-red` directory when you started node-red (so your installed nodes are missing)

Comment: You need to share a lot more information, edit the question to include the Node-RED console output when it starts up as this log will include a list of the nodes it can not find.

Comment: @SteveR you do not need to be in `userDir` when you start Node-RED

Comment: True - depending upon *how* you start it... since I don't use the scripts, and just run `node` from the command line, it does matter for me. I just cd into the directory of the project I want to run, and start it manually. It's also possible that she has a local and a global install, and depending on her login or path it's picking up a different install.

Comment: Hey everybody, thanks for the quick response. I managed to solve the issue, I deleted node-modules and reinstalled them and that did the trick.